# Raw audio packets to WAV/GSM_MS compliant file on Android

Tags: android, audio, wav, audio-recording

I'm looking for the logic/code-snippet which can convert my raw audio packets to WAV/GSM_MS complaint audio file. I'm able to capture data from android device mic and store it in buffer or file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your raw data is already in interleaved, All you need is to prepend wave header in the beginning. The wave header format is given here https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

When you create a new wave file always write the header (with data length field set to zero as you dont know the entire size of data you wish to write at the at beginning of recording) then start writing your data immediately after the header, once you are done writing the data to it seek to the beginning and update the data length field.
here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129173/Writing-a-Proper-Wave-File is a code for the same.

Comment: thanks for the pointer... Actually after including the wav headers its working. Could you please send a link or some code for gsm_ms files? As this one is the priority for me.

Comment: for gsm_ms files you have to set appropriate Compression code(49 (0x0031) in this case) in format chunk of wave header  http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html#fmt

Comment: Hi Potter, I'm capturing stream of audio packets which I want to convert into libgsm_ms encoding without saving it into a file or converting it into some xyz format and then reconvert it into libgsm_ms standard.